# Программно исключить непечатаемые листы autocad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocad

Пишу плагин для autocad на C#

Программно создаю листы (layout) и передаю их на печать(Publisher)

При формировании DSD файла в самом конце появляется описание НЕСУЩЕСТВУЮЩИХ листов(!!!)

т.е. Если скрипт создал 2 листа, то выходной DSD файл получается такого вида:

```
[DWF6Version]
Ver=1

[DWF6MinorVersion]
MinorVer=1

[DWF6Sheet:test-LIRPOCAD_3]
DWG=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Layout=LIRPOCAD_3
Setup=
OriginalSheetPath=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Has Plot Port=0
Has3DDWF=0

[DWF6Sheet:test-LIRPOCAD_4]
DWG=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Layout=LIRPOCAD_4
Setup=
OriginalSheetPath=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Has Plot Port=0
Has3DDWF=0

[Target]
Type=6
DWF=d:\Users\amg2\Desktop\LirpoCAD.pdf
OUT=d:\Users\amg2\Desktop
PWD=

[AutoCAD Block Data]
IncludeBlockInfo=0
BlockTmplFilePath=

[SheetSet Properties]
IsSheetSet=FALSE
IsHomogeneous=FALSE
SheetSet Name=
NoOfCopies=1
PlotStampOn=FALSE
ViewFile=FALSE
JobID=0
SelectionSetName=
AcadProfile=
CategoryName=
LogFilePath=d:\Users\amg2\Desktop\publish.log
IncludeLayer=TRUE
LineMerge=FALSE
CurrentPrecision=
PromptForDwfName=FALSE
PwdProtectPublishedDWF=FALSE
PromptForPwd=FALSE
RepublishingMarkups=FALSE
PublishSheetSetMetadata=FALSE
PublishSheetMetadata=FALSE
3DDWFOptions=0 0

[DWF6Sheet:test-LIRPOCAD_5]
DWG=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Layout=LIRPOCAD_5
Setup=
OriginalSheetPath=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Has Plot Port=0
Has3DDWF=0

[DWF6Sheet:test-LIRPOCAD_6]
DWG=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Layout=LIRPOCAD_6
Setup=
OriginalSheetPath=D:\Users\amg2\Desktop\test.dwg
Has Plot Port=0
Has3DDWF=0
```

в данном DSD файле листы LIRPOCAD_3 и LIRPOCAD_4 действительно существуют, а листы LIRPOCAD_5 и LIRPOCAD_6 - нет. Откуда они берутся не могу понять

Исходный код формирования DSD:

```
public void Publish(Template tmpl)
{
    if (TryCreateDSD())
    {
        Publisher publisher = AcAp.Publisher;
        PlotProgressDialog plotDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, this.sheetNum, true);
        publisher.PublishDsd(this.dsdFile, plotDlg);
        plotDlg.Destroy();
    }
}
```

/// В переменной this.layouts Хранятся листы созданные скриптом

```
private bool TryCreateDSD()
{
    using (DsdData dsd = new DsdData())
    using (DsdEntryCollection dsdEntries = CreateDsdEntryCollection(this.layouts))
    {
        if (dsdEntries == null || dsdEntries.Count <= 0) return false;

        if (!Directory.Exists(this.outputDir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(this.outputDir);

        this.sheetNum = dsdEntries.Count;

        dsd.SetDsdEntryCollection(dsdEntries);

        dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PwdProtectPublishedDWF", "FALSE");
        dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("PromptForPwd", "FALSE");
        dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("IncludeLayer", "FALSE");
        dsd.SetUnrecognizedData("3DDWFOptions", "0 1");
        dsd.SheetType = SheetType.MultiDwf;
        dsd.NoOfCopies = 1;
        dsd.DestinationName = this.pdfFile;
        dsd.IsHomogeneous = false;
        dsd.LogFilePath = Path.Combine(this.outputDir, LOG);

        PostProcessDSD(dsd);

        return true;
    }
}

private DsdEntryCollection CreateDsdEntryCollection(IEnumerable<Layout> layouts)
{
    DsdEntryCollection entries = new DsdEntryCollection();

    foreach (Layout layout in layouts)
    {
        DsdEntry dsdEntry = new DsdEntry();
        dsdEntry.DwgName = this.dwgFile;
        dsdEntry.Layout = layout.LayoutName;
        dsdEntry.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.dwgFile) + "-" + layout.LayoutName;
        dsdEntry.Nps = layout.TabOrder.ToString();
        entries.Add(dsdEntry);
    }
    return entries;
}
```

P.S.: Могут ли это быть viewport?